# Telegram (simplest) inline bot send photo 2 times on iOS

Tags: ios, client, inline, telegram, telegram-bot

I have an inline bot similar to @pic and it works ok, when I type query word I can see pictures appear so I can choose one and send to a chat. The problem is when I do - 2 copies of same result are sent. This happens only on iOS client. On Android, PC and other platforms only one picture is being sent. I have checked all logs (the bot is done in Node.js) and for every request I have a single response. It seems to be a iOS client bug, although @pic bot works fine. Has someone encountered this bug or have an idea of what can cause it?

Example of answerInlineQuery response object

```
{
"inline_query_id": "817150058382989968",
"results": [
    {
        "type": "photo",
        "id": "se090",
        "photo_url": "http://www.shadowera.com/secardbot361/se090.jpg",
        "thumb_url": "http://www.shadowera.com/secardbot361/se090.jpg",
        "photo_width": 344,
        "photo_height": 480,
        "title": "Tracking Gear",
        "description": "You can view the hands of opposing players.",
        "caption": "king"
    },
    {...
```

UPDATE:
So I have created a simplest possible inline bot in node.js @iosinlinebot (you can try it) AND you have the same exact behaviour: only on iOS devices you will send 2 images to the chat once tapped on the result.
Here is the code:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
        console.log(event);
        const https = require("https");
        let answer = {
            inline_query_id: event.inline_query.id,
            results: [{
                    type: "photo",
                    id: "abcd",
                    photo_url: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jVXglyWWL5J2y1vRN-7Jy3_ozvvZc4w5486IAkbAIrWcNN_vn7YuIvhc1JDtGq43BqGl=s180",
                    thumb_url: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jVXglyWWL5J2y1vRN-7Jy3_ozvvZc4w5486IAkbAIrWcNN_vn7YuIvhc1JDtGq43BqGl=s180",
                    photo_width: 180,
                    photo_height: 180,
                    title: "title",
                    description: "description",
                    caption: "test"
                }],
            cache_time:1 
        };
        let postBody = JSON.stringify(answer);
        let options = {
            hostname: "api.telegram.org",
            port: 443,
            path: "/bot" + process.env.TOKEN + "/answerInlineQuery",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': postBody.length
            }
        };

        let postreq = https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            const body = [];
            res.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));

            res.on('end', () => {
                let j = body.join('');
                console.log(j);
                //context.done(JSON.parse(j));
            });
        });
        postreq.write(postBody);
        postreq.end();
};
```

this is an event object (coming from telegram):

```
{
  "update_id": 12345678,
  "inline_query": {
    "id": "123456789123456789",
    "from": {
      "id": 123456789,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "Firstname",
      "username": "username",
      "language_code": "it-IT"
    },
    "query": "test",
    "offset": ""
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Sedric Heidarizarei we were able to find the problem. It is a telegram iOS client bug. If `InlineQueryResultPhoto` object contains *caption* field, you user will post 2 images to the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important to close the Begin and the End of your regex with `^` and `$`.
For example a user with this regex `/^[/]start/` can use `start` and `start a` and `start b` as Bot command And will allow Them to receive your photo, But with `/^[/]start$/`, The user must enter the exact /start Command.

1: Use This Module: [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api)
2: And Send Your Photo:

```
bot.onText(/^[/]start$/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    parse_mode: 'Markdown',
    reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [[{
                text: '',
                callback_data: 'back'
                }]]
        }
  };
  bot.sendPhoto(msg.chat.id, 'AgADBAADn64xBoABCx8L8trMV9eMqgDAAEC', opts); // Your Photo id
});
```

Notice:
Open an empty project and just use and  check your `InlineQueryResultPhoto`.

**update:**
That is a Telegram bug for For temporary use, remove `caption` from your `let answer ={}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my question has nothing to do with bot commands. My bot works in inline mode. It sends to telegram all regular answerInlineQuery object (I will add it to my question). The problem is when user select one of the photo results on client to post in chat, 2 images are posted (on iOS only).

Comment: Which library are you using? And can you share a part of your code? I can check that 1 days later because I'm on Vacation.  Open an empty project and just use and  check your `InlineQueryResultPhoto`.

Comment: I do not use any library (not even for http), my code is really slim, written in in vanilla node.js. It sends correct "answerInlineQuery" with an array of "InlineQueryResultPhoto" results to the TG API via https and receive "ok" from TG. I might create another basic inline bot just to test if the same bug occurs again for only iOS clients...will let you know... BTW you can try my bot @secardbot, use some keyword like "fore", "hero", "item". Note how it sends 2 photos in chat on iOS devices.

Comment: In iPhone 5S I had 2 Messages, 1(photo+caption)and  2 ( only caption), I'm wating for you.

Comment: I have created new bot just to test the thing, you can see my question updated. As you can see it is the simplest possible inline bot, but still it gives the same bug on iOS.

Comment: Hi I want to run and check your code in node.js project, How do you get `event.inline_query.id,` from user?

Comment: I have updated question with example of `event` object, it's essentially an input from telegram.

Comment: when I run your code, i'm getting `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID"}` ,  each `InlineQuery` have an ID and msg query  and we Should awnser to That msg id, I mean I want to send `answerInlineQuery` to my id, bot.answerInlineQuery(msg.id, opts);